# цикл if не работает в кроне

Tags: bash

Сделал скрипт, который вращается по крону раз в минуту и отсылает в телеграм срочку со словом error, если она появлялась за прошедшую минуту.

```
#!/bin/bash
date_today=$(date +%d -d "+179minute")"."$(date +%m -d "+179minute")"."$(date +%Y -d "+179minute")
date_time=$(date --date 'now +179 minute' | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/\(.*\).../\1/')
error_send=$(grep $date_today /var/log/fmserver/sms.log | grep $date_time | grep -i error)

if [ -n "$error_send" ];then
    curl  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request 'POST' --data "{\"chat_id\":\"@chat_id\",\"text\":\" $error_send \"}" "https://api.telegram.org/bot123213123:AAGrfsdfgfy62T-U6hurQhBViiEc5MH-DvN0g/sendMessage"
fi
```

Вручную все работает замечательно, а вот по крону он присылает одну и ту же строчку каждую минуту.

```
* * * * * root /bin/bash /opt/sms.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: ну, в `date_today`, как я понимаю, должно попасть `date +"%d.%m.%Y" -d "+179minute"`. тут вроде понятно, хотя неясно, для чего так сложно написано. а вот что, по-вашему, должно попасть в `date_time`? у вас там какая-то невнятная обработка строки, представляемой совершенно по-разному с разными локалями. даже мне как человеку не понятно, что вы там хотели получить. про компьютер, тупое электронное устройство, и речи нет.

Comment: если в `date_time` вы хотели поместить результат `date +"%R" -d "+179minute"`, то лучше так было и написать, чтоб компьютеру не приходилось додумывать, с какой правильной локалью надо запустить программу date, чтобы получить то, что вам требуется. // p.s. кстати, а зачем вы прибавляете везде по 179 минут? у вас та программа, что пишет в лог, работает в ещё ненаступившем будущем?

Comment: на сервере время по utc, а лог по мск, поэтому так.

Comment: вручную все окей - отрабатывает, а по крону отправляет все ошибки за текущий день, а не за прошедшую минуту

Comment: какие ошибки-то? я ж говорю вручную через консоль все отрабатывает верно, а через крон нет.

Comment: я же написал выше. ну, ок, могу ещё раз написать: в переменную `date_today` логичнее будет помещать вызов не трёх команд, а всего одной: `date +"%d.%m.%Y" -d "+179minute"`. и в переменную `date_time` лучше сразу помещать то, что вам требуется (`date +"%R" -d "+179minute"`), вместо попытки обработать конвейером команд данные, которые выглядят по-разному в разных локалях.

Comment: спасибо большое, все получилось! а почему крон не хотел воспринимать правильно эту переменную? обычно все работало....

Comment: программа cron тут совершенно ни при чём. сравните вывод `$ LC_ALL=C date --date 'now +179 minute' | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/\(.*\).../\1/'` и `$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 date --date 'now +179 minute' | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/\(.*\).../\1/'` . ну и вообще: зачем вызывать три программы, когда можно обойтись запуском одной?

Comment: понял.
 плохо изучил man утилиты date) еще раз спасибо!